# Shifting a logic vector to a bit

Tags: if-statement, vhdl, clock, fpga, bit-shift

I have a 8-bit logic vector which should be shifted to an output.

```
constant CR:std_logic_vector:(7 downto 0):="11000000";
```

I'm trying to use an index for CR and each value belonging to the specified index...

```
Q<=CR(i);
```

I make count i for 0 to 7 by if statements to achieve shifting. But i have some doubts about that. Am i on the right way? Or is there a better way to do this like shifting functions. (Of course thiş operation should be synchronously with clock to be able to syntetize.)

I am so new at VHDL so thanks for the responses.

Comment: Your case appears to demonstrate the value of reputation on stack exchange sites.  You haven't accepted a single answer to any of your previous questions.  You can derive the iteration range for the loop from the declaration of `CR` and if you need the order reversed use the attribute 'REVERSE_RANGE. Otherwise see my answer to your question [How can i generate a pulse train to give output in common way?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25783320/how-can-i-generate-a-pulse-train-to-give-output-in-common-way/25795603#25795603)

Comment: Sorry for that. I didn't know that i could accept an answer because of my low rep. I like brainstorming and a question may asked from different ways and solutions for a problem may differ, too. I guess it makes no matter with stack exchange sites and it's a good way of understanding. Thank you for all of your responses.

Comment: Also notice the spurious colon following std_logic_vector in your declaration of CR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, really, my comment to your question wasn't a solicitation for your accept an answer, I'm not that hard up for reputation points, honest.

I meant it was hard for the potential question answerer to  put any effort into your questions, plus your reputation won't increase either.

It seem's a bit awkward putting a clock condition inside a loop statement (as opposed to a generate statement, so let's try a separate counter instead:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity shft_log_vec is
    port (
        rst:    in  std_logic;
        clk:    in  std_logic;
        Q:      out std_logic
    );
end entity;

architecture foo of shft_log_vec is
    constant CR:       std_logic_vector (7 downto 0) := "11000000";
    signal bit_ctr:  natural range CR'REVERSE_RANGE;  

begin

    Q <= CR(bit_ctr);

INDEX_CTR:
    process (clk, rst)

                           -- uninitialized default value is 0
    begin
        if rst = '1' then  -- will only run after a rst after the first time, use reset
           bit_ctr <= 0;
        elsif bit_ctr < CR'HIGH and rising_edge(clk) then  -- you could add an enable
           bit_ctr <= bit_ctr + 1;  -- integer arithmetic and comparison.
        else
        end if;
        -- because you need clock evaluation  for sequential operation in there, no loop 
        -- statement.  Reverse the bit order by using 'RANGE instead.

    end process;

end architecture;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity tb_shft_log_vec is
end entity;

architecture foo of tb_shft_log_vec is
    signal rst: std_logic := '0';
    signal clk: std_logic := '0';
    signal Q:   std_logic;
begin

DUT:
    entity work.shft_log_vec 
        port map (
            rst => rst,
            clk => clk,
            Q  => Q
        );

CLOCK:
    process 
    begin
        wait for 20 ns;
        clk <= not clk;
        if Now > 360 ns then
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;

STIMULUS:
    process
    begin
        wait for 1 ns;
        rst <= '1';
        wait for 20 ns;
        rst <= '0';
        wait;
    end process;

end architecture;
```

Notice the pointer for `CR` is `bit_ctr` which is a constrained integer That counts from 0 to 7 then stops.

If you wanted `CR` to come out in the reverse order (7 first) use `'RANGE` and `'LOW` instead of `'REVERSE_RANGE` and `'HIGH.`

When the test bench is simulated we see the values of Q take on `CR(0)` to `CR(7)` each clock rising edge and stop waiting on a reset.

[image: tb_shft_log_vec.png]
*(the image is a link to itself full size)*

Using a reset, there's an implication both the generator and the recipient know which clock edges to sample `Q` on.  It may be prudent to switch to a synchronous reset share between both the generator and the recipient, depending on how far the signal Q is being routed (as across clock tree boundaries).

Notice the similarities and differences to the answer to your previous question in the comment links.  This way using attributes allows you to change the size of CR easily.